# Black screen after update (Nvidia driver)

Tags: nvidia, release-odin, black-screen, nvidia-driver

I did a system update on my *elementary OS 6 Odin* system with *Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti*. After a reboot I'm left with a black screen, unable to log in. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gets me into TTY2, but I am unable to launch `lightdm` and log in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [regression](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-hwe-5.11/+bug/1943086) in Ubuntu 20.04. Anybody who has `nvidia-driver-470` and updates to kernel version `5.11.0-34-generic` will experience black screen. A temporary walkaround is to log in to a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and remove all nvidia-related packages:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-470 nvidia-kernel-common-470 ...
```

You can just type `sudo apt purge nvidia` and hit <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to see all the nvidia packages that are still installed.

After doing this, I could get into Pantheon just fine.

**If you've also experienced this, please check “This affects me” in the Ubuntu [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-restricted-modules-hwe-5.11/+bug/1943086)!**