# Elementary OS 6 going straight to tty1, startx not working

Tags: release-odin

I installed Elementary OS 6 a couple weeks ago, and it was working perfectly fine until I ran some updates today. It boots into tty1, Ctrl + Alt + F7 doesn't seem to do anything, and running startx isn't working.

Here is the log output for startx: https://pastebin.pl/view/ccf9cae6 (It was too big to fit in the post)

At this point I'm considering a reinstall of the OS, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: from tty1, login into your account and execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. The issue is most likely a problem during the installation of the nvidia graphics drivers.

Comment: This might be a related issue: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/28776/19079

Comment: @m93a Thanks for that, it's all working now, thanks.